# Custom taxonomy in wordpress, + 1 new input

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

It is possible add a new input in custom taxonomy?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But, more important, *why* do you need that? Because, adding is one thing, making it work is another.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and it's pretty easy. You can use the tutorial [here](https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/).

This is the code you'll need to use:

```
<?php
// Add term page
function pippin_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    // this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Example meta field', 'pippin' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" id="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" value="">
        <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','pippin' ); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'pippin_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: please view the photo. I want to add input in post section.

Comment: I've done something similar and it's clearly possible. But the code I use is a bit different, though it could help you. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/helenhousandi/1573966